# How to get the element from the ref in REACT

Tags: reactjs

I have a third-party library on my site that requires to send an element in a parameter like:

```
window.third-party("test",document.getElementById("test"),...)
```

This is working fine in some of my websites, however, I have one built on REACT where is not working because when the call is done inside componentDidMount() it still does not exist.

I've been trying using refs, however, I'm not able to get the DOM element and if I pass the ref like:

```
window.third-party("test",this.myElement.current,...)
```

it does not work :(

---

This is how I define the ref:

```
<Input
                    type="password"
                    id="password-register"
                    ref={this.myElement}
                  />
```

It does not work because this.myElement.current is not returning an element.

How can I get the element inside **componentDidMount()** function?

Many thanks

Comment: Is `<Input>` a component you wrote?

Comment: Yes, it is a component

Comment: Is `Input` a functional or class component?

Comment: `Input` will need to use `forwardRef` if it's going to take in `ref`. Have you done so? This is easiest if Input is a function component, but alternatives exist for class components.

Comment: it is a component from react-validation library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation

Comment: in any case is returning:

n {props: {…}, context: {…}, refs: {…}, updater: {…}, id: '4e80f740-8482-48cb-b5a2-963be03ccc0c', …}

But not an element...

Comment: react-validation has not been updated in 4 years – you might want to look for an alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it looks like the [react-validation library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-validation) has not been implemented to forward refs. The only refs it exposes are refs to the react elements, not the dom elements.

You might be able to work around this by getting a ref to an element higher up the tree and using vanilla javascript to search for child elements, something like this:

```
containerElement = createRef();

componentDidMount() {
  const inputElement = this.containerElement.current.getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
  window.third-party("test", inputElement,...)
}

render() {
  // ...
  return (
    <div ref={this.containerElement}>
      <Input type="password" id="password-register>

      </Input>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findDOMNode` to get the element, if the `Input` is a class component  `ref` will return the instance of the class.

`findDOMNode` will return the DOM node from the class component.

```
import {findDOMNode} from 'react-dom';

class YourComponent extends React.Component {
  myElement = React.createRef()

  componentDidMount() {
    const element = findDOMNode(this.myElem)
    window.thirdParty("test",element,...args)
  }

  render() {
    return <Input
    type="password"
    id="password-register"
    ref={this.myElement}
  />
  }
}
```

**TL;DR** `findDomNode` will provide you the DOM element irrespective of class/functional component.

Comment: `findDOMNode` is not recommended in new code (see the warning in http://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#finddomnode)

Comment: I agree they should avoid this, but it may still be a useful answer. They're going to have to hack around the insufficiencies of the react-validation library (or ditch the library), and findDOMNode would be one hacky way to do so.